# In Django, how can I programmatically check that an IntegrityError is related to a particular uniqueness constraint of the model?

Tags: django, django-models, orm

For example, if I have this model:

```python3
# foo/models.py
# Python standard library
from uuid import uuid4

# Django
from django.db import models


class Foo(models.Model):
    uuid_1 = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, unique=True)
    uuid_2 = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, unique=True)
```

And then I create instances of it:

```python3
# Python standard library
from uuid import uuid4

# Django
from django.db import IntegrityError

# foo app
from foo.models import Foo

const_uuid_1 = uuid4()
const_uuid_2 = uuid4()

first_foo = Foo.objects.create(uuid_1=const_uuid_1, uuid_2=const_uuid_2)

# violate `uuid_1` uniqueness
try:
    Foo.objects.create(uuid_1=const_uuid_1)
except IntegrityError as e:
    pass

# violate `uuid_2` uniqueness
try:
    Foo.objects.create(uuid_2=const_uuid_2)
except IntegrityError as e:
    pass
```

So how can I tell the two uniqueness violations apart, programmatically? In my application, business requirements dictate that my program is allowed to automatically handle and correct one of the violations, but not the other (which must be reported back to the user).

Comment: I think a better way would be to override the clean method in model(or form) and perform validation there. That way you can easily check which field causes the error and then you can directly send the response back to user rather than waiting for exception to occur at database level. (personal opinion)

Comment: @coderDude wouldn't that still be prone to race conditions unless I wrap the whole thing in an `@atomic` and **lock the table**? Otherwise, the clean method may validate OK, but when it's actual time to INSERT, a new row may have popped up in the table that causes conflict, and I would be back at square one (having to tell which constraint is being violated).

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a problem. I have never worked on projects with large scale for this problem to have occurred. I usually simply put an except IntegrityError in save and return with "Some error has occurred. Please try again" (after performing validation in clean). So if the person tries again, they get the cause

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `__cause__` attribute of the exception to get access to the lower level exception. According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions):

> As per [PEP 3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134), a `__cause__` attribute is set with the original (underlying) database exception, allowing access to any additional information provided.

If you are using postgresql with psycopg you can use [`e.__cause__.diag`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.Diagnostics) for more debug info.

Comment: That's a great hint! `e.__cause__.diag` also has a `constraint_name` property. If there's a way to reliably associate the `constraint_name`, I'm pretty much set.